# VIM - First command on multiple command on same line being ignored

Tags: vim, command

I am extracting information from several files and I wrote the following command:

```
:g!/Value/d | %s/.*=//ge | %s/\;//ge | %y
```

and it basically does:
 'delete lines without "Value" | delete everything up to the = sign | remove ";" | copy all to register'

but the first `:g!/Value/d` is being ignored, it seems the `%y` is somehow causing it to be ignored as

```
:g!/Value/d | %s/.*=//ge | %s/\;//ge
```

properly cleans the document.

I also tried to get a log from the command execution there was nothing helpful there.

I don't see how the last command could affect the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` command separator has different precedence depending on the command, as [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) explains. For the `:global` command, it (and following commands) is **considered to be part of the command arguments itself**. That means that your substitutions and yank is not executed once (after the `:global`), but actually *on every line that `:global` picks*!

You've already found the correct workaround: By wrapping the command in `:execute` (which respects the `|` command separation) and quoting it, the following commands are only evaluated after the first command.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to work around this

```
execute 'g!/\.Value/de' | %s/.*=//ge | %s/\;//ge | %y
```

This will produce the expected behavior, still it is unclear why the bar would not work for the `:g` command.